# Invoke-command hanging on 1 or 2 machines. How to disconnect them?

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I am running the following invoke command on a bunch of servers, cycling through the list in the text file. When they are all done, i run some other code to consolidate all of the results. So the jobs themselves are running in parallel fine, and i'm getting results back for each machine, but because 1 or 2 machines are hanging up, my entire script will never finish running because i need to consolidate all the data once all the jobs finish.
I am not sure why, but a couple of machines are hanging up preventing the entire script from finishing.

I have searched similar topics but cant seem to find a way to disconnect or kill the jobs running on the machines that have been hanging or running for a long duration, lets say 30 minutes. I tried setting timeout values, but seems to have no effect.
Here is my code currently..

```
$TimeOut = New-PSSessionOption -IdleTimeOut 120000
icm -ComputerName (Get-Content C:\temp\servers.txt) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -SessionOption $TimeOut -ThrottleLimit 15 -ScriptBlock{My code gathering data on each machine here}
#This is where i run the code to consolidate all the data once all jobs above are complete.
```

thank you